# Stuck in reusing an android studio archive?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have this library that I want to use among many applications. It's located here:

```
c:\company\libraries\library
```

And in my environment variables I've mapped `c:\company` to `CompanyProjectsRoot`.

Now I want to use it in projects A and B. Inside `settings.gradle` of each project A and B I have:

```
include ':library'
project(':library').projectDir = new File(System.getEnv('CompanyProjectsRoot'), '/libraries/library')
```

and in their `app`'s `build.gradle` files I have:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
}
```

But when I try to build A and B, I get this error:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could
>   not resolve project :library.
>
> Could not resolve project :library. Required by:
>       project :app
>
> > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :library: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

I'm stuck at this point on what the problem is. I searched and couldn't find anything similar to my problem. Could you help?

Comment: the library are you adding is .jar or .aar ?

Comment: it's `aar`, but does it make a difference?

Comment: Sorry for late response.  Have you imported the library i.e File>Project Structure >plus sign and then Import .JAR/.ARR Package ?